# Code Signing Certificate Providers (2016)

Tags: code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I need a cheap certificate to sign my application so I can get rid of SmartScreen warning : https://playgunscape.com/downloadgunscape/Windows8_SS_1.png .

Also I'm having problem with false positive from various antivirus programs each time I release an update. As far as I've heard, signing the exe might fix this problem too .

I found an offer from comodo, 2 years for 150 $ .  But it's still a lot of money . 
https://cheapsslsecurity.com/sslproducts/codesigningcertificate.html

Does anyone know a better offer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately "Cheap" is relative to results.  The amount of time it is probably taking you and frustration is probably worth paying for and "EV" Class 3 certificate (Extended valuation)
Class 3 certificates are a step above the Class 2. Class 2 does not require “Extended Validation”. However the “EV” code signing certificates combine all of the regular benefits of digitally-signed code with a rigorous extended validation process. They represent the gold standard for authentication and security in code signing certificates. EV code signing certificates adhere to strict validation standards from the CA/Browser Forum and to Microsoft specifications. Enhanced authentication is provided via an encrypted token containing the private key. But the down side is they cost about $350 per year... Good news... It will fix the problem.